# How can I hide the user input being typed into raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

I am creating a program that takes user input through raw_input and puts it into a text file in code (as in a = 2, c = 6 for example). I want to be able to hide what the user is typing into the program before they hit enter (and are then shown the coded text)

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
npt = raw_input (("26 Char Cyper Sentence: ").lower())
L = list(npt)
r = raw_input ('{name of file}: ')
txt='.txt'
me=r+txt
folder = open(me, 'a')
while True:
 a = L[0];b = L[1];c = L[2];d = L[3];e = L[4];f = L[5];g = L[6];h = L[7];
 i = L[8];j = L[9];k = L[10];l = L[11];m = L[12];n = L[13];o = L[14];p = L[15];
 q = L[16];r = L[17];s = L[18];t = L[19];u = L[20];v = L[21];w = L[22];x = L[23];y = L[24];z = L[25]
 txtt = raw_input (('{\n').lower())
 txt = txtt.lower ()
 new1 = txt.replace ('a', a)
 new2 = new1.replace ('b', b)
 new3 = new2.replace ('c', c)
 new4 = new3.replace ('d', d)
 new5 = new4.replace ('e', e)
 new6 = new5.replace ('f', f)
 new7 = new6.replace ('g', g)
 new8 = new7.replace ('h', h)
 new9 = new8.replace ('i', i)
 new10 = new9.replace ('j', j)
 new11 = new10.replace ('k', k)
 new12 = new11.replace ('l', l)
 new13 = new12.replace ('m', m)
 new14 = new13.replace ('n', n)
 new15 = new14.replace ('o', o)
 new16 = new15.replace ('p', p)
 new17 = new16.replace ('q', q)
 new18 = new17.replace ('r', r)
 new19 = new18.replace ('s', s)
 new20 = new19.replace ('t', t)
 new21 = new20.replace ('u', u)
 new22 = new21.replace ('v', v)
 new23 = new22.replace ('w', w)
 new24 = new23.replace ('x', x)
 new25 = new24.replace ('y', y)
 new26 = new25.replace ('z', z)
 print (new26.lower ())
 folder.write ((new26).lower ())
```

I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 10 and have already tried the 'getpass' module and the 'curses' module (I couldn't get either to work:( ). Unfortunatly I cannot show you how I used these as I scrapped the copy I made with each one in it but feel free to show me how I can (correctly) use these modules on the code above. What can I do? And also, would it work if I just changed the color of the input font...and how?

Comment: Please show us your code and how you used the getpass library.

Comment: Okay, I will add that now.

Comment: The above code works fine but doesn't hide the input.

Comment: Have you tried: import getpass; pwd = getpass.getpass(prompt=‘Your secret Word: ‘);

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, it seems like you're working on an encryption project but `Cyper` is not how you spell `cipher`.

Comment: @Fabrizio_P: The program doesn't use any sort of password, Baduker is right, this is an encryption program. You type in a 26 character string and it uses each character from that to encrypt your text.

Comment: @Baduker: Sorry about the spelling...I didn't even notice it till you pointed it out.

Comment: @Barra: mine was only an example. In your case it would be `import getpass; npt = getpass.getpass(prompt='26 Char Chyper Sentence: ');`

Comment: @Fabrizio_P: Thank you for the example. I tried what you said and it didn't work. But also, it is this line-> txtt = raw_input (('{\n').lower())  <- that has the input I want to hide. I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: Please if you say it didn’t work post us your code and eventually if there were any errors.

Comment: @Fabrizio_P: Sorry, I did a bit of tinkering around with your suggestion after posting that comment and have got it to work.Sorry for not posting the code...Do I now post the working code? The problem was your suggestion didn't work in IDLE when I ran it but it works after I saved and ran it in command prompt. Thank you!

Comment: I will put it as an answer so that people can see the solution if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the getpass python module to hide the user's input.

A minimal working example will be:

```
import getpass
secret_word = getpass.getpass(prompt="Enter your secret word: ")
print(secret_word)
```

Where `secret_word` is the word you want to hide in the terminal.

**UPDATE**

In your case the line would be:

```
txtt = getpass.getpass (('{\n').lower())
```

Comment: txtt = getpass.getpass (('{\n').lower())  is my corrected line using that suggestion. Thank you:)